# Failed to open stream: Permission denied using fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

While using `fpdf` class in ubuntu linux apache server, I got above warning. Then there is an fatal error:

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Unable to
>   create output file: result.pdf' in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/fpdf.php(1022): FPDF->Error('Unable to
>   creat...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/generate.php(185):
>   FPDF->Output('result.pdf', 'F') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/fpdf.php on line 271

Comment: Did you check file permissions?

Comment: Actually , i think there is nothing like permission. There is output option on which my error has been recovered. I have changed 'F' as 'D' In pdf->output

Comment: Thats because option `D` does not involve the filesystem

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by making doing the following in my PHP file:

```
$pdf->Output('result.pdf', 'D');
```

`$pdf` is my object of the `FPDF` class. I set the parameter as `'D'`, which forces a file download with the provided name.

Comment: Are you actually answering you question, or is this an edit to your original post? If it's just additional information, delete this and edit the question.

Comment: No, actually I have got answer of my question.

Comment: @Celeritas I am working on my english and trying to improve it .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permissions issue.  Whatever user the webserver runs under must have permission to create/modify the file.  This is very likely not the same user you login as.  If you have access, su as the webserver user (eg. sudo su - apache), then try to create the file manually.  The shell command "touch" will do the trick.  That will tell you if the webserver has access.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that file **result.pdf** is not open anywhere when you run script. if it's open somewhere else then TCPDF can't open it.